# Should there be two first-post review queues?

Tags: discussion, review

When I am doing first-post reviews, I notice that I treat questions and answers differently.

For first-post questions I think am quite relaxed. No spam, reasonably clear, good references and so on then it is an approved.

While for first-post answers, I skip most posts of them because they are outside my area of expertise, and I think a more knowledgable reviewer should have a look.

This made me wonder if there should be two queues, one for the first question and another for the first answer.

Lets discuss, or is the way I review just wrong?

Comment: What time of day do you usually review first posts? Every time I've gone to the review queue it's empty at the level I can review (there always seem to be close votes but it's above my score).

Comment: I don't see anything "wrong" with how you differentiate first post reviews of question vs. answer.  However the first-post review may occasion making constructive comments, so that new users get off on a good footing.

Comment: I see what you mean, Alonzo. I can review first posts, late answers, low quality posts and suggested edits. A few minutes ago I went through three suggested edits, and that felt like a lot. Though right now there are 30 close votes, but I can't review those either.

Comment: I am closing this question, as recent updates to the review queues have implemented the feature discussed here.  It does not seem that there is further discussion to be had (though a *new* meta post on the updates would not be inappropriate if there are problems which need to be discussed).

Answer (score 38):

In a way, this already exists. If someone prefers to review only questions, or only answers in First Posts queue, they can filter accordingly:

[image: filter]

The setting is "sticky", meaning the site will remember your preference next time you go into the queue.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now there are different review queue for answers and questions namely First Questions and First Answers. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions) is the link for first questions and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/) is the link for first answers.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/1052107) is the link informing about the announcement.